# Why is 'nav_menu_item_args' filter's $item argument empty?

Tags: menus, filters, hooks, navigation

I'm trying to hook into [`'nav_menu_item_args'`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_item_args/) filter in method `start_el()` in [`class Walker_nav_menu`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/):

```
/**
* Filters the arguments for a single nav menu item.
*
* @since 4.4.0
*
* @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
* @param WP_Post  $item  Menu item data object.
* @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
*/
$args = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_args', $args, $item, $depth );
```

Here is my code:

```
function filter_nav_menu_item_args($args, $item, $depth)
{
        if ($args->menu->slug == 'countries')
        {
            $args->link_before = print_r($item, true); // <-- Outputs nothing
        }

    return $args;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_item_args', 'filter_nav_menu_item_args' );
```

But I get problem when trying to use the `$item` argument. It's empty. And I'm very sure I'm calling a menu. The `$args` array contains all the right values.

So, is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you using a custom walker at all, with its own `start_el()` method?

Comment: No, not custom walker. But what I understand WordPress is using the walker as well. I mean. It works to write anything instead of `print_r($item, true)`. So I know the `start_el()` method is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filters (and actions) need to be declared with the number of arguments accepted by the callback; it is the fourth parameter of `add_filter()` (default `1`):

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_item_args', 'filter_nav_menu_item_args', 10, 3 );
function filter_nav_menu_item_args( $args, $item, $depth ) {

    print_r( $item );

    return $args;

}
```

See [`add_filter()` for reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/).

Comment: ps: the `true` in `print_r` is for returning the value